# Issue with IE10 passing domain information

Tags: domain, internet-explorer-10, sharepoint

I currently administrate a sharepoint site located on our university's intranet. I have program participants who are located at another school across town and need to access our sharepoint.

The sharepoint is correctly pointed out, as I can easily access it from home and a number of students have told me they have no issues accessing it on personal computers.

the problem is accessing it from school computers at the other school. IE tries to pass their domain to my sharepoint, which obviously is not the right domain.

Is there a way to make IE not pass the local domain as login information to a remote sharepoint server?

Comment: This sounds like a server issue to me, SE or SF seem like better choices for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in IE 10:

- Go to **Tools->Internet options**
- Go to the **Security** tab
- Select *Trusted sites*
- Click **Sites** button
- Add the website
- Uncheck **Require server verification**
- Click **Close**
- Click **Custom level...** button
- At the bottom, under *User Authentication*, choose **Prompt for user name and password**
- Click **OK**